# Using OnNcHItTest for a CWnd not CDialog

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I have a CWnd Derived object used in a dialog.  I need to be able to drag it anywhere in the dialog.  I have a code overriding OnNCHitTest for moving a dialog dragging it from a place other than the title bar.  Is there any equivalent code to do the same to move this CWnd.  The following code isnt working.

```
UINT CBaseSliderBtn::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    UINT ret=CWnd::OnNcHitTest( point );
        if (ret == HTCLIENT)
            return HTCAPTION;

}
```

If this isn't the right way, please suggest other optimum method to drag the slider.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example simply simulate mouse actions, as their occur with dialog title. And the dialog title allows you to drag the dialog.
As for your custom window, it is probably a child window and does allow dragging using a window part. You should process [mouse input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645533(VS.85).aspx) to implement dragging.

Comment: Thanks but I figured what i was doing wrong.  I used the classname static during creation. I had to register my own class. Thanks Anyways